# How to make animation responsive in unity5

Tags: android, animation, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I am developing a game in which I use collider2d animation   and other collider when 2 collider has same tag it gives score and when 2  collider does not have same tag then game over  it works fine in small screen like cell phone but it did not works in large screen like taet  because it find collider in middle if screen. Is animation need to responsive or collider needs to responsive because without animation its works fine